# How to create an ActiveRecord object via 'where' query that contains json?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, arel

`title` (type `string`) persists, but `notes` (type `json`) does not...

```
b = Book.where(title: 'Lalala').where("notes ->> 'regional_office': 'foo'").create
=> #<Book:0x00007fabab7303f8 id: nil, title: 'Lalala', notes: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
b.save!
b.title
=> 'Lalala'
b.notes
=> nil
```

(Why is `notes` `nil`?)

Instead, I must assign the `json` `notes` separately...

```
b = Book.where(title: 'Lalala').where("notes ->> 'regional_office': 'foo'").create
b.notes['regional_office'] = 'foo'
b.save!
b.notes
=> {'regional_office': 'foo'}
```

Is there a way to do it without a separate assignment?

Comment: I've never seen the `->>` operator used before. Are you sure that's correct? I would instead try to replace with something like `where(notes: {"regional_office" => "foo"})`

Comment: Rails cant and wont parse the custom sql in these kind of queries and therefore cannot create a scope that would allow it to set the notes attribute on create. There is no way around it, i think.
@obiruby this is a Postgres JSON operator :) perfectly valid

Comment: Thanks, @MarianTheisen - that makes sense.